# Android: actions showing on the right edge when setting action view instead of icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, action-menu

I am adding action menu items to the action bar dynamically and because I want a "badge" effect, I am setting views to the items instead of just drawable icons. My problem is that when I have items which have their views set, they are also aligned to the right edge of the action bar. I want to have some sort of inset, but nothing seems to achieve that. I tried setting margins on the action view layouts, setting insets in the XML and programmatically, but nothing is changing. Does anyone know how I can make it so that the actions don't appear right at the edge?

This is what I see now:

[image]

And I want to have some sort of padding/margin between the icon and the right edge of the action bar, like on the left side between the left edge and the title.

Here is some code:

View of the action menu items (res/layout/navbar_action.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="53dp"
              android:layout_height="53dp"
              android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
              android:layout_marginRight="12dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navbar_icon"
        android:layout_width="44dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|left"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/navbar_badge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:background="@drawable/navbar_badge_circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_caption"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Setting up the action bar and the action menu in the base activity:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final int MENU_PRIMARY = 0;
    public static final int MENU_SECONDARY = 1;

    protected ActionBar actionBar;

    boolean hasPrimaryAction = false;
    String primaryActionTitle;
    MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener primaryActionListener;
    View primaryActionView;
    boolean hasSecondaryAction = false;
    String secondaryActionTitle;
    MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener secondaryActionListener;
    View secondaryActionView;

    ...

    protected boolean initToolbar() {
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    ...

    public void setAction(String title, Drawable icon, int actionNumber) {
        if (actionNumber == MENU_PRIMARY) {
            hasPrimaryAction = true;
            primaryActionTitle = title;
            primaryActionView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.navbar_action, null);
            ImageView iconView = (ImageView) primaryActionView.findViewById(R.id.navbar_icon);
            iconView.setImageDrawable(icon);
            primaryIcon = icon;
        } else if (actionNumber == MENU_SECONDARY) {
            hasSecondaryAction = true;
            secondaryActionTitle = title;
            secondaryActionIcon = icon;
            secondaryActionView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.navbar_action, null);
            ImageView iconView = (ImageView) secondaryActionView.findViewById(R.id.navbar_icon);
            iconView.setImageDrawable(icon);
        }
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    public void setActionBadge(int actionNumber, int badgeCount) {
        if (actionNumber == MENU_PRIMARY) {
            if (primaryActionView != null) {
                TextView badgeView = (TextView) primaryActionView.findViewById(R.id.navbar_badge);
                if (badgeCount > 0){
                    badgeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    badgeView.setText(String.valueOf(badgeCount));
                } else {
                    badgeView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        } else if (actionNumber == MENU_SECONDARY) {
            if (secondaryActionView != null) {
                TextView badgeView = (TextView) secondaryActionView.findViewById(R.id.navbar_badge);
                if (badgeCount > 0) {
                    badgeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    badgeView.setText(String.valueOf(badgeCount));
                } else {
                    badgeView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    public void removeAction(int actionNumber) {
        if (actionNumber == MENU_PRIMARY) {
            hasPrimaryAction = false;
        } else if (actionNumber == MENU_SECONDARY) {
            hasSecondaryAction = false;
        }
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (hasPrimaryAction) {
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, Menu.NONE, primaryActionTitle).setActionView(primaryActionView).setOnMenuItemClickListener(primaryActionListener).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        }
        if (hasSecondaryAction) {
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, secondaryActionTitle).setActionView(secondaryActionView).setOnMenuItemClickListener(secondaryActionListener).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Layout of the action bar:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/actionBarBg"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/actionBarBg"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:titleEnabled="false">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/action_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/search_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/navigation_icons_margin_left"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/navigation_icons_margin_right"
                android:background="@drawable/search_icon_dark_bg"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/parent_cart"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right">
  <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/navbar_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/home"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/nom_product"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:background="@drawable/red_circle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Red Circle :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    <size
        android:height="20dp"
        android:width="20dp" />



</shape>
```

Comment: Wow, I thought the padding would mess up my layout, but it actually worked without misplacing the badge! Thanks!